# How to make input verification in a separate function? the program should take the input sequence 1 and 0

Tags: python, function, input, user-input

How to make input verification in a separate function? the program should take the input sequence 1 and 0

```
def check(SEQ):
    for i in SEQ:
        isinstance(i, int)
    if not (set(SEQ) == {0, 1} or set(SEQ) == {1} or set(SEQ) == {0}):
        return False
    else:
        return True


def main():
    SEQ = [i for i in input("Enter the sequence 0 and 1   ").split()]
    while not check(SEQ):
        print("Invalid values ")
        SEQ = [i for i in input("Enter the sequence 0 and 1 ").split()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You already have a function called check, that checks the user input. But it can be massively simplified. In the first step do `SEQ = list(map(lambda x: int(x), SEQ.split))`. Then check if `all(map(lambda x: x==1 or x==0, SEQ))`

Comment: Instead of three cases, why not check if the input is a *subset* of `{0,1}`? Also -- you don't need `if ... else` to convert a boolean into a boolean. Just return the comparison itself. Those 4 lines in the function can be replaced by the 1 line `return set(SEQ) <= {0,1}` (fine print: this comparison would validate the empty string, but your original code would not. Since the empty string *is* a binary sequence, albeit a trivial one, this is a feature of my suggestion rather than a bug).

Comment: As far as the edit goes -- I don't see how an edit which deletes OP's *code* from a question can be valid. I thus rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
def check(value):
    return all(map(lambda x: x=='1' or x=='0', value.split()))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to either convert to int or use `'0', '1'`?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot about the type. Changed to string.